# Parallel.Foreach vs Foreach for data migration process

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a list of Vehicles..and for each vehicle I am doing some migration job..

```
foreach (vehicles)
{

1 : Do database table migration for that vehicle
2 : Call an API and save them to database

}
```

To improve the performance I am making it parallel like :

```
Parallel.Foreach(vehicles)
{
--same
}
```

1. Is this the correct approach? Because my understanding is, it will create new thread for each requested vehicle and things should work fast.
2. Will making parallel TASK improve it much?
3. Is it good to keep a maximum number of parallelism? If yes, how to decide that factor?

Comment: Have a look [this](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CFAQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FB%2FC%2FF%2FBCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D%2FWhenToUseParallelForEachOrPLINQ.pdf&ei=1a5nUtL0HcrX0QXA84GYAg&usg=AFQjCNEPIq11VZKlic-cw6qK-Hw2bGWmng&sig2=zFCYLSUg7U4OQbXKZSD8kQ&bvm=bv.55123115,d.d2k)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - Thanks for the link..It seems i am on right track then..Can you assist a bit on my 3rd point

Comment: I am not quite clear what you mean by *maximum number of pallellism*. Please explain?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I meant..in parallel.foreach we have an option `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }` which enable us to control the number of parallel threads...Is there a way to assign this a correct value to get maximum performance benefit..

Comment: RE your third point, `Parallel.ForEach()` is pretty good at creating the maximum number of threads without oversaturating the CPU. Only use `ParallelOptions` if you want to limit the maximum threads - but I think you'll find that the defaults are fine.

Answer (score 5):

1. It is the correct approach if you have little or no dependency between each `Vehicle` item. In other words, you (ideally) shouldn't have any `lock` (or other synchronization primitives) in the body of the `Action` performed over each `Vehicle`. However, if you do have `lock`s in your code, they should be on a portion of code that executes significantly faster than the rest of the method:

   ```
   Parallel.ForEach(vehicles, v => 
   {
       // Some code that takes long to execute
       lock(_syncRoot)
       {
           _totalProcessedVehicles ++;
       }  
   })
   ```

   `Parallel.Foreach` will *NOT* create a thread per `Vehicle` instance - it will spawn several threads and will give each thread a chunk of your collection to process. The number of threads depends on your hardware and available resources.
2. No. `Parallel.Foreach` uses `Task`s internally and by doing so elevates the burden of code overhead from you. Also, tasks are scheduled and executed on different threads using the same logic as above: each thread processes a chunk of `Task`s.
3. I would not recommend specifying a maximum degree of parallelism - let the `CLR` do that for you; in the vast majority of cases it will do a great job. However, if you *do* want to limit the degree of parallelism, there is an overload for `Parallel.Foreach` which accepts a parameter of type [`ParallelOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx). Use the property [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) to limit the degree of parallelism.

Comment: Thanks..Can you explain a bit more on..`it will spawn several threads and will give each thread a chunk of your collection to process` - Is not it like..it will create many threads for each vehicle?

Comment: The CLR tends to make a reasonable decision about how many threads to use for CPU-bound work. But accessing the DB is not CPU-bound, so setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is probably a good idea.

Comment: Yes..Indeed..I am just not sure how to get the value of MaxDegree..currently I am testing it locally for = 4

Answer (score 2):

1. Approach is ok, just make sure your function 1 and 2 are thread safe (don't share common resources or at least sync their usage)
2. probably it depends, what the bottleneck is, e.g. if you have just a single CPU and your problem has the CPU as the bottleneck parallelizing will not bringing you anything. If you have multiple cores (CPUs) than for a CPU limited problem the parallelizing will be very beneficial.
   In your case the limitation can also be the database into which you migrate the data, flooding it might even make it worse.
3. again it depends on the bottleneck you have, if it is the CPU a parallelisation of a higher degree than your CPU cores count is will not bring you anything, it will in contrast slow it down as the switching of the threads will eat up the resources. As a rule of thumb I choose mostly for CPU limited problems number of cores -1, so that the rest of the system can still be responsive.

For small or even simple workloads inside the foreach loop the overhead for initializing the Parallel.Foreach might also eat up the benefit.

In general give it a try and decide from case to case.

Comment: Thanks for those great suggestions..I will get aware of CPU cores we have in production server..How does it affect to memory?